# How to check the dll come from which source [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, dll

Due to bad management, I have several copies of similar vb.net program.  These vb.net program will generate the dll for other projects to use.  Now, is there any way to know which of these sources generate this dll?

Thanks for advance for any suggestions.

Comment: put every copy into different folders an launch them one by one. or launch them one by one and check the dll creation date

Comment: Would that be the same as the file creation date that you can examine by viewing the file properties in Explorer?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  But actually the source are checked out from tortiseSVN.  So, the file creation date do not reflect the actual creation.  Also, the source are checked in by someone else, so cannot confirm whether the check-in date is meaningful or not.

Comment: Please confirm the situation. 1) You have a dll file that could have been generated from one of several project versions. 2) These projects do not increment the assembly version. 3) Your goal is to match the dll to the project that generated it.  Is that an accurate sequence?  If so, you could do a file content comparison.